# combine two columns and create one in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

as a step to create my dimensional data model I need to combine two columns and create one new referencing to the units of values from each columns.

I have among other tables one table that has yearly GDP of a country. the table has two columns GDP represented as MONEY (unit) and the other year change (% as unit). in my fact table I would like to have both in same column but with a new columns representing dimension (units). because of that I am wondering how to merge these two columns and create another one that would specify if the value comes from the column with units (%) or (money). this applies to other entities in the data model that can have different units for same variable.
thanks for your help!

Consider orginal data format :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQLNS.png)

We have quartal dates a series of economic indicator and their values, on the right side there is another table with dimensions of the economic indicator.

What I need is to change data so it should be like this (fact table with quartal date granularity) :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoAhi.png)

Comment: Could you please add what you have tried so far? errors/blockers? and sample input and expected result?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Please check my origian lpust with updated info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced the above scenario with a sample data and able to combine the columns like below.

**My sample data of two columns Money and Unit:**

[image]

Use **derived column** transformation for the `res` column which will have the Unit or Money values. To know which column value, I have used another column `which_value`.

Expression for `res` column:

```
iif(isNull(Money),Unit,Money)
```

Expression for `which_value` column:

```
iif(isNull(Money), 'Unit', 'Money')
```

[image]

**Result in Data preview:**

[image]